# InterlockedExchange vs. InterlockedExchangePointer

Tags: c++, atomic, visual-c++-6, interlocked

What is the difference between `InterlockedExchange` and `InterlockedExchangePointer`?

Are

```
if( 0 != InterlockedCompareExchange( ( void** ) &_myVariable
                                   , temp
                                   , 0
                                   ) )
```

and

```
if( 0 != InterlockedCompareExchangePointer( ( void** ) &_myVariable
                                          , temp
                                          , 0
                                          ) )
```

equivalent?

I have to port code to VC6 which does not know of the `Interlocked[...]Pointer` functions.

**Edit:**

I know from my own experience, that VC6 is *extremely* buggy and that no one shall use it anymore.

However, I am not a decision-maker and an answer to the original question would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You have to port code … *to* VC6? Forget it. VC6 is discontinued, *extremely* buggy and dead. Do not develop new code for/with it, and migrate existing projects *away* from it – it *will* be cheaper in the long run.

Comment: Have you tried http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683590.aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms683609.aspx? (Also, AFAICS the first one would not compile, and the second one has a redundant cast)

Answer (score 5):

`InterlockedCompareExchange` takes a 32 bit variable.

`InterlockedCompareExchangePointer` takes a pointer-size variable, which is different depending on the target architecture.

If you target 32 bit and only 32 bit architectures it will be fine, however whenever you change the target architecture to 64 bit, the following will compile and behave nasty:

```
InterlockedCompareExchange( ( LONG volatile * ) _myPointer , 1, 0 ) );
```